# Why is the arccos of a negative ratio the obtuse angle?

Tags: trigonometry

This is a repost of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363628/why-is-the-arccos-of-a-negative-value-an-obtuse-angle) since it was not answered and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774642/trigonometry-obtuse-angles-and-a-negative-length) it was not answered clearly.

if we can no longer think about triangles when in any quadrant other than the first, how else can I visualize or think about the angle and it's sin,cos,tan ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: For any point on the unit circle given the angle in radians then $\cos$ is the projection onto the $x$ axis, $\sin$ is the projection onto the $y$ axis, and $\tan$ is the slope. This works in every quadrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking in terms of the sides of a right triangle with angle $\theta$ so $\cos \theta = \frac {adjacent}{hypotenuse}$ and $\sin \theta = \frac {opposite}{hypotenuse}$ only works for $0 < \theta < 90$.

To extend it to *any* angle it is better to think of it this way:

Imagine a unit circle centered at $(0,0)$ and with radius $1$.  Imagine a point $(x,y)$ on the circle (that would mean $x^2 + y^2 = 1$) so that the angle made by the point, the center of the circle, and the $x$-axis in the positive direction, forms the angle $\theta$.  Then we call $x = \cos \theta$ and $y = \sin \theta$.

If $0 < \theta < 90$ then the point is in the first quadrant and $0 < x=\cos \theta < 1; 0< y=\sin x < 1$.  And $(x,y), (x,0), (0,0)$ form a right triangle with hypotenuse$=1$ and base angle $\theta$.  And $x = \cos \theta = adjecent = \frac {adjacent }1=\frac {adjacent}{hypotenuse}$ and $y = \sin \theta = \frac {opposite}{hypotenuse}$.

[image]

If $90 < \theta < 180$ then the point is in the second quadrant and $-1 < x =\cos \theta < 0; 0 < y= \sin  theta< 1$.  And $(x,y), (x,0), (0,0)$ form a right triangle with hypotenuse $1$ but it's extending the adjacent leg in the opposite (negative direction) and the base angle is $180 - \theta$.  And we have $y=\sin \theta = \frac {opposite}{hypotenuse = 1}$ and $x =\cos \theta =  -\frac {adjacent}{hypotenuse = 1}$.

[image]

And if $180 < \theta < 270$ then the point is in the third quadrant and $-1 < x =\cos \theta < 0; -1 < y=\sin \theta <0$.  And $(x,y), (x,0),(0,0)$ forms a right triangle but it's extended in the negative direction.  The base angle is $\theta - 180$ and $y = \sin \theta = -\frac {opposite}{hypotenuse = 1}$ and $x = \cos \theta = -\frac {adjacent}{hypotenuse = 1}$.

And if $270 < \theta < 360$ then the point is in the fourth quadrant and $x$ is positive and $y$ is negative.  We get a right triangle with base angle $360 - \theta$ and $x = \cos \theta = \frac {adjacent}{hypotenuse}$ and $y = \sin \theta =-\frac {opposite}{hypotenuse}$

=======

Okay, full disclosure.... I stole those images from other sites without permission.  But credit where due they are from https://www.expii.com/t/using-unit-circle-to-find-sine-or-cosine-5219 and http://flipping-a-classroom.weebly.com/unit-circle-and-the-six-trig-functions.html

I haven't read those sites but... they look like they'll have the information you are interested in if you want more information.

Answer (score 1):

$\arccos:[-1,1] \to [0, \pi]$

If $x\in (0,1)$ then $\arccos x \in \big(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\big)$

If $x\in (-1,0)$ then $\arccos x \in \big(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \big)$

In words.

1. The arccos of a positive number less than 1 is an angle in the first
   quadrant, an acute angle.
2. The arccos of a negative number greater than than -1 is an angle in the second
   quadrant, an obtuse angle.